# how to unload a Form inside a Panel in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, panel

how can i unload a form inside a panel
my code is :

```
frmInvoiceOverview.Close()
    frmInvoiceOverview.Dispose()


    With frmInvoiceOverview
        .TopLevel = False
        MainPanel.Controls.Clear()
        MainPanel.Controls.Add(frmInvoiceOverview)
        .BringToFront()
        .reloadTable()
        .Show()
    End With
```

If i "load" it again the Form Load event will not fired.

what do i wrong ?

Comment: I think you're referencing the default instance of frmInvoiceOverview. If so, it generally leads to confusing behaviour. Create an instance of frmInvoiceOverview and reference that and see how it goes.

Answer (score -1):

You are invoking a class like `Form` doing that which a simply `Control` (eg. `Panel`) can do.
That means you have more heavy runtime objects (even not so significant).
However after calling `.Dispose` in a `Form` (or whatever else `Object`) needs to be ***initialized*** like

```
   frmInvoiceOverview = New InvoiceOverview With {
            .TopLevel = False,
            .FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None}
```

before calling methods or setting its properties then lifetime cycle ***restart*** again